# mysql join respect to a column

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I got two mysql table like this

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl1 (
`id` INTEGER(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`name` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl2 (
`tbl_id` INTEGER(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`id2` INTEGER(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`email` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
FOREIGN KEY (`id2`) REFERENCES tbl1(`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Here is example data in tbl1

```
1   hello
2   world
3   happy
4   end
```

and example data in tbl2

```
2   1   me@mail
3   2   my@mail
4   4   you@mail
```

now I want to select name and email joining two table. Here is the sql

```
select name,email from tbl1 t1,tbl2 t2 where t2.id2 = t1.id;
```

with it i'm getting

```
hello   me@mail
world   my@mail
end     you@mail
```

but I want all row from tbl1

```
hello   me@mail
world   my@mail
happy   null or nothing or 0
end     you@mail
```

here i am stuck. any help will be appreciated.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select name,email 
from tbl1 t1
LEFT JOIN tbl2 t2 
  on t1.id = t2.id2;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91ca7/1).

Your current query is using an `INNER JOIN` which will only return the rows that are matching in both tables.  The `LEFT JOIN` will return all records in `tbl1` even if there is no matching row in `tbl2`.

If you need help learning join syntax here is a [visual explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)